# How to run multiple C# Az function apps locally in Visual Studio Code on Mac that are created in visual studio 2019 windows?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, macos-catalina, azure-function-app

Stack overflow users. I am new to development on Mac. I have no option to use windows machine, I'm using basic spec Macbook pro 2015 which restricts me on installing virtual box or parallel to run windows. Which leaves me no choice but to use Mac. Any suggestion or help would be really great thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run multiple function apps. After some investigation i found these things.

1. Install azure cli https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-macos
2. Found this page on git hub https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/wiki/Multiple-function-projects
   This worked for me.

Thank you for all the time in looking into my question.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Function Core Tools allows you to run your function apps locally--this is how VS Code executes your functions on the backend.

Assuming you have multiple functions which interact with each other, and depending on how you have implemented that interaction, you may be able to start a function manually by navigating to its directory in Terminal and running `func start` to have one function running the background, then updating your second function to reference the local URI and starting your debugging in VS Code for the second function.